# Prolog remove elements which have the same value as the index from the list

Tags: prolog

I have a task to remove all elements which have the same value as the index from the list. I have this code but it does not work.

```
remove(_, [], []).
remove(position, [H | T1], [H | T2]) :-
    H =:= position,
    next_position = position + 1,
    remove(next_position, T1, T2).
    
remove(position, [H | T1], T2) :-
    H =\= position,
    next_position = position + 1,
    remove(next_position, T1, T2).

:-remove(1,[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],Res),
    write(Res).
```

The main mistakes were in syntax. Also conditions has to be swiped. Now it changed and program works.

SOLUTION:

```
remove(_, [], []).
remove(Position, [H | T1], [H | T2]) :-
    H =\= Position,
    NextPosition is Position + 1,
    remove(NextPosition, T1, T2).
    
remove(Position, [H | T1], T2) :-
    H =:= Position,
    NextPosition is Position + 1,
    remove(NextPosition, T1, T2).

:-remove(1,[1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],Res),
    write(Res).
```

Comment: You have quite a few errors in your program. Variables start with an upper case letter, e.g.: `Position` instead of `position`. Also don't use unification (`=/2`) to compute an arithmetic expression. Use `NextPosition is Position + 1` instead of `next_position = position + 1`

Comment: Also, whats your expected output ? For example for the input `[1, 2, 2, 4]` would it be `[1, 4]` or `[1, 2]` ?

Comment: @gusbro You were right, there is some mistakes in my syntax . Now my program works well. Thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the modifications already pointed out by Gusbro, you also need to invert the conditions used to include/exclude elements from the input list:

```
remove(_, [], []).

remove(Position, [H|T1], [H|T2]) :-
    H =\= Position,                % include element if it is different from its index
    Next_position is Position + 1,
    remove(Next_position, T1, T2).

remove(Position, [H|T1], T2) :-
    H =:= Position,                % exclude element if it is equal to its index
    Next_position is Position + 1,
    remove(Next_position, T1, T2).
```

Examples:

```
%  index      1 2 3 4
?- remove(1, [1,2,2,4], Res).
Res = [2] ;
false.

%  index      0 1 2 3
?- remove(0, [1,2,2,4], Res).
Res = [1, 2, 4] ;
false.

%  index      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
?- remove(1, [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Res).
Res = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] ;
false.
```

To avoid **spurious choice point**:

- Use a *wrapper* predicate to maintain the arguments in the original desired order.
- In the *helper* predicate, change the order of the first two arguments, to take advantage of Prolog's first argument indexing.
- Use [`->`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2) to avoid the need to evaluate a deterministic condition and also its negation.

Thus, an improved version of this predicate is as follows:

```
improved_remove(Start, List, NewList) :-
    remove_loop(List, Start, NewList).

remove_loop([], _, []).

remove_loop([H|T1], Position, L) :-
    (   H =\= Position
    ->  L = [H|T2]
    ;   L = T2 ),
    Next_position is Position + 1,
    remove_loop(T1, Next_position, T2).
```

Examples:

```
?- improved_remove(1, [1,2,2,4], Res).
Res = [2].

?- improved_remove(0, [1,2,2,4], Res).
Res = [1, 2, 4].

?- improved_remove(1, [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], Res).
Res = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].
```